# How to get the most repeated value of x column grouped by z column - ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a select that returns a table such as:

| weekOfTheYear | mostRepeatedID |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | a |
| 01 | b |
| 01 | a |
| 02 | b |
| 02 | b |
| 02 | a |

and what I need is:

| weekOfTheYear | mostRepeatedID |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | a |
| 02 | b |

so that each week of the year only appears once and the mostRepeatedID for each week, is the value that appears the most.

Comment: The value that occurs most often is called the statistical mode and the function to retrieve it is `STATS_MODE`. If, however, there are two or more values with the top count, one is chosen arbitrarily. If you don't want this to happen, you need another approach: Count rows per weekOfTheYear and repeatedID. Then determine the top count per weekOfTheYear, then show those values. I.e. think in several steps till you get where you want to be.

Comment: STATS_MODE works perfectly fine for the values with the most frequency, do you know what could work to get the values with the least frequency?, oracle documentation doesn't seem useful with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to have is descendingly sorted counts of each `mostRepeatedID` grouped by `weekOfTheYear` values such as

```
WITH t1 AS
(  
 SELECT weekOfTheYear, mostRepeatedID, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM t -- your table
  GROUP BY weekOfTheYear, mostRepeatedID 
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       weekOfTheYear,
       MAX(mostRepeatedID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY cnt DESC) 
                           OVER (PARTITION BY weekOfTheYear) AS mostRepeatedID
  FROM t1
```

But this case, there's a drawback(*if it's not problem for you*) that the ties might occur for those counts, then the last alphabetically ordered value is returned(here `b`) as MAX implies.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YziOzBc1)</kbd>

Comment: The ties aren´t a problem, thank you very much, it also works for the least repeated value if I change `DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY cnt DESC` for `DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY cnt ASC`  right?

Comment: Hi @AlejandroHernández you're welcome. The other case would be `DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY cnt [ASC]` (ASC is optional, indeed redundant).

Comment: @AlejandroHernández Rather than generating all the rows and then filtering them using `DISTINCT`, you can just generate one row for each partition using `GROUP BY weekOfTheYear` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/En7dlbx2).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function to find the rows with the maximum count and then filter to only return the rows with the first rank:

```sql
SELECT weekOfTheYear,
       mostRepeatedId
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY 
       weekOfTheYear,
       mostRepeatedId
ORDER BY
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         PARTITION BY weekOfTheYear
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
       )
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (weekOfTheYear, mostRepeatedID) AS
SELECT '01', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02', 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02', 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '03', 'c' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| WEEKOFTHEYEAR | MOSTREPEATEDID |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | a |
| 02 | b |
| 03 | a |
| 03 | b |
| 03 | c |

*Note: If you only want a single row-per-group then use `ROW_NUMBER` rather than `DENSE_RANK` and, if you want the minimum count then `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` rather than `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w3DpgyAf)

Comment: Wow, that's the way what I wanted to construct in my mind ... Perfect !